# How do I use a pre-populated field to use in an email alert?

Tags: administration, automation

I have a lookup field in the Opportunity Object that's being auto-populated by Process Builder. The value in the field depends on criteria that's selected within the Opportunity. Is there a way to use the field in an email alert within the Additional Emails to be able to cc whoever is in that field at the time of the email alert??

[image: Auto-populated field]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, NO

Email Alerts rely on fields of type Email to be exposed in the Setup UX and for related objects, you are pretty much limited to any OOTB related Contact.Email

I suggest you migrate to Flow and use the OOTB Flow Core action: `Send Email` that gives you much more control over the to: and cc: addresses while still exploiting email templates (and avoiding using Email Alerts).

*Process Builder is deprecated*

Comment: I have a Flow setup for the email alert, I just need to figure out how to email the user that's in that field at the time of the email alert...

Comment: My suggestion is to not use Email Alert but use the Send Email core action.   Your OP stated Process Builder so sorry I was confused